# Wagtail RoutablePageMixin fail to route page when DEBUG=True

Tags: python, django, http, content-management-system, wagtail

I am using Wagtail/CodeRedCMS to set the website.
RoutablePageMixin is inherited in my model (named WriteLandingPage). And "route" is used to redirect the request to a certain custom view. my code is below.

**model.py**

```
class WriteLandingPage(RoutablePageMixin, CoderedArticlePage):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Write Landing Page'

    template = 'coderedcms/pages/write_landing_page.html'   

    @route('')
    def submit(self, request):
        article_index = ArticleIndexPage.objects.all()[0]
        from .views import submit_topic
        return submit_topic(request, article_index)
```

**views.py**

```
def submit_topic(request, article_index):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    form = EditForm(data=request.POST or None, label_suffix='')
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        submit_page = form.save(commit=False)
        submit_page.slug = slugify(submit_page.title)
        topic = article_index.add_child(instance=submit_page)
        if topic:
            topic.unpublish()
            topic.save_revision(submitted_for_moderation=True)
            return render(request, 'coderedcms/pages/submit_topic_success.html', {"user": request.user})
    
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'edit_index': article_index,
    }
    return render(request, 'coderedcms/pages/submit_topic.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticlePage
        fields = ['draft', 'title']
```

Everything works just perfect when DEBUG=True.
But It fails to read the page when I turn DEBUG to False. The following messages show on the backend console.

```
[18/Jun/2021 01:41:04] "GET /write-landing-page/ HTTP/1.1" 500 940
```

Am I missing any setting?

Error msg. below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whitenoise/middleware.py", line 59, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/core/views.py", line 24, in serve
    return page.serve(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/routable_page/models.py", line 121, in serve
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/website/models.py", line 568, in submit
    return submit_topic(request, article_index)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/website/views.py", line 24, in submit_topic
    return render(request, 'coderedcms/pages/submit_topic.html', context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 971, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 63, in __str__
    return self.render()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 78, in render
    return mark_safe('\n'.join(chain.from_iterable(getattr(self, 'render_' + name)() for name in MEDIA_TYPES)))
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 78, in <genexpr>
    return mark_safe('\n'.join(chain.from_iterable(getattr(self, 'render_' + name)() for name in MEDIA_TYPES)))
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 81, in render_js
    return [
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 82, in <listcomp>
    format_html(
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 112, in format_html
    return mark_safe(format_string.format(*args_safe, **kwargs_safe))
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 99, in conditional_escape
    return text.__html__()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/js_asset/js.py", line 66, in __html__
    js = static(self.js) if self.static else self.js
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 167, in static
    return StaticNode.handle_simple(path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 153, in url
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 132, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 423, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js'
```

Comment: Looks like an error trying to access a static file, have you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: It may also be that ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js is missing from the project, and it was just failing silently when DEBUG was false.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct, I forget the collectstatic.